# Update Table options as user fills out the input more specifically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am now working in a POS System. My goal is, as the input is getting updated by the "keyup", the results that match this keyup show in a table.

Something like this:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AE43.jpg)

I think I have the code completed, just missing to echo the results in a table. This is my actual JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("tablaClientesEnVenta").dataTable({
  bFilter: false, bInfo: false
 });

$("#inputNombreCliente").on('keyup', function(){

$("#tablaClientesEnVenta").css("visibility", "visible");
if (!$("#inputNombreCliente").val()){
  $("#tablaClientesEnVenta").css("visibility", "hidden");
}
console.log("tecla detectada");
var nombreCliente = $(this).val();
console.log(nombreCliente);
var datos = new FormData();
datos.append("nombreCliente", nombreCliente);

$.ajax({
  url:'ajax/crear-venta.ajax.php',
  method: "POST",
  data: datos,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success:function(respuesta){
    console.log(respuesta);
}
  });

});
});
```

This is my AJAX Code to call the function:

```
<?php
  require_once '../controladores/clientes.controlador.php';
  require_once '../modelos/clientes.modelo.php';

  class AjaxVentas{
   public $nombreCliente;
   public function ajaxNombreCliente(){
    $item = "nombre";
    $valor = $this->nombreCliente;
    $respuesta = ControladorClientes::ctrMostrarAjaxClientes($item, 
    $valor);

    echo json_encode($respuesta);
 }
}

 if (isset($_POST['nombreCliente'])) {
  $cliente = new AjaxVentas();
  $cliente -> nombreCliente = $_POST['nombreCliente'];
  $cliente -> ajaxNombreCliente();
 }
```

This is the function that calls out for the model:

```
  static public function ctrMostrarAjaxClientes($item, $valor){
   $tabla = "clientes";
   $respuesta = ModeloClientes::mdlMostrarAjaxClientes($tabla, $item, 
   $valor);
   return $respuesta;
  }
```

Finally, the function that calls out the data from the DB:

```
 static public function mdlMostrarAjaxClientes($tabla, $item, $valor){
  $statement = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla 
  WHERE $item = :item");
  $statement->execute(array(":item" => $valor));
  return $statement->fetchAll();
 }
```

As a conclusion, I would like to know what I am missing, since the `console.log(respuesta)` in the JS is giving me an error. Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

In your AjaxVentas class;

```
ControladorClientes::mdlMostrarAjaxClientes($item, $valor);
```

The static method requires 3 arguments ($table, $item, $valor) not two($item, $valor) being passed above

## Edited

```
Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :item");
```

Table name is not being passed

Comment: But that one isn't static, is it?

Comment: The issue is the table name not being passed.

Comment: But where should I echo the results stored in the json_encode($respuesta)?

Comment: Yea, the table is being passed from the ajax receiver to the controller, and the controller sends the table name to the model.

Comment: Array(0)length: 0__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: An empty array, where it should return me the results that match what is being typed in the input.

Comment: An empty array doesn't mean an error, are you sure there is a match of the item in your DB? You might want to check that first.

Comment: I did. My database has the value of what I am typing in the input.